# Calculate inter-event time per group in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a dataset 'albums'. It looks like this:

```
uid   date1  
1     30-01-2012
1     5-02-2012
1     19-03-2012
1     12-06-2012   
2     8-02-2012
2     14-05-2012
2     17-06-2012
```

I want to calculate the mean and the standard deviation PER UID of the time between rows. The rows in the data frame are order per uid and ascending date.

How can I do this? The inter-event time of the first row per group would always be 0 as there are no rows to compare with. I don't want the 0 to skew my mean or standard deviation.

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? What is your desired output based on this input?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I'm sorry. Still learning to code in R and found this too difficult. My desired output is the uid, mean of the interevent time and the stdev of the interevent time in a data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some solutions.  The assumed input is shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.  Note that in that Note we create a `"Date"` class column for `date1` (rather than a `"factor"` or `"character"` class column).

**1)** `aggregate`.  No packages are used.

```
stats <- function(x) {
    delta <- diff(x)
    c(mean = mean(delta), sd = sd(delta))
}
aggregate(date1 ~ uid, DF, stats)
```

giving:

```
  uid date1.mean date1.sd
1   1   44.66667 39.52636
2   2   65.00000 43.84062
```

**2) dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
   group_by(uid) %>% 
   summarize(mean = mean(diff(date1)), sd = sd(diff(date1)))
```

giving:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

    uid          mean       sd
  (int)        (dfft)    (dbl)
1     1 44.66667 days 39.52636
2     2 65.00000 days 43.84062
```

**3) data.table**

```
library(data.table)

data.table(DF)[, list(mean = mean(diff(date1)), sd = sd(diff(date1))), by=uid]
```

giving:

```
   uid          mean       sd
1:   1 44.66667 days 39.52636
2:   2 65.00000 days 43.84062
```

**Note:** The input data frame `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "uid   date1  
1     30-01-2012
1     5-02-2012
1     19-03-2012
1     12-06-2012   
2     8-02-2012
2     14-05-2012
2     17-06-2012"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$date1 <- as.Date(DF$date1, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Would this ignore the 0 from the first row?

The code did not work. I get NAs on all rows.

Comment: No zero is produced by `diff` in the first place.  Did you convert the dates to Date class as shown in the note?  You can see the answers that the varoius R solutiions produced so clearly it does work and if it does not on some data frame that you have not shown us then there is some difference that you haven't explained.